# MAF error after replacing short ram intake and MAF

Tags: mazda, mazda-3, maf

I bought my 2004 Mazda3 used and it had a Short ram intake.  I replaced the filter with a K&N filter that was slightly longer than the one that came with the car.  It was jammed in there bending the intake a bit.  It ran great for a few months than I ran into an issue where the car was shuddering when taking my foot off the gas.  I decided to try to fix it by cutting a bit of the intake tube(im stupid).  Anyway it immediately started having MAF errors and check engine light, as well as the engine revving randomly and seeming like it was choking the engine.  I bought a brand new version of the same intake and put it on thinking it would solve it and it did not, same issue so i got a new MAF. Didn't really solve the issue.

The car is running much smoother but really rich, I can smell the gas when I get out of the car.  I've cleared the codes and they come back right away, the car idles really oddly at times, dropping to 500 and bouncing back up to 1k over and over.  I'm at a loss on what to do now, about to just go get a pick and pull stock intake if I cant get some help from here.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Has your car been tuned before? Is the diameter of the intake tube different than that of what is original?

Comment: Prior to me owning it I do not know if it was tuned.  I have not tuned it myself.  The diameter is exactly the same as the intake that was on it when i got it.  I got the same corksport short ram that was on it to try to solve the issue of me shortening the tube.  The issue started right after I shortened the intake and figured just getting another one without altering it would solve it.

Comment: There may be two issues. If your K&N uses a soaked oil filter, excessive oil may contaminate the maf sensor, resulting in maf error codes.  Clean a maf sensor with maf sensor cleaning spray. The other issue may be incorrect air flow to the maf sensor from aftermarket intake mods. Incorrect airflow can result in maf errors. Upsetting factory tuned airflow to maf sensors isn't  discussed until mystery problems pop up.